# Validity of Random Phase Approximation in 2D/3D semimetals

Tags: solid-state-physics, field-theory, approximations, many-body, weyl-semimetal

In, for instance, [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.113.105502) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.04636.pdf) the authors look at many-body effects in two- and three-dimensional semimetals, which have a low-energy quasiparticle dispersion relation of the form $\varepsilon_{\bf k} = \hbar v_F |{\bf k}|$. In both papers they use the Random Phase Approximation, which is a resummation of all bubble diagrams in the Dyson equation for the photon propagator. About the range of validity of the approximation they note

> We  also note that although our results are obtained within RPA, they
>   should be essentially exact for realistic Dirac-Weylsystems  where 
>   the  typical  degeneracy  factor $g\gg 1$  by virtue of the
>   many-valley multiple Dirac cone nature of these  systems [$g=24$  in
>   the recently discovered Weyl semimetal TaAs, and all higher-order
>   many-body corrections are suppressed by higher powers of $1/g$.

Is there an easy way to see that all many-body corrections that do not contribute to the RPA bubble-sum, are surpressed by a factor of $1/g$? Naively I would say that for any electron bubble in the photon propagator, you have to sum over all electron species, which gives you a factor of $g$. I don't, however, see how all other higher-order diagrams are surpressed.

Comment: Do you mean to write $g>>1$? I can't understand their statement otherwise.

Comment: @KFGauss Yes, of course you are right, it was a typo and I fixed it.

Comment: In any case the statement is a bit strange to me at least because RPA relies on the high **density of carriers** in the usual approach, not a high number of **species**. These two things aren't the same I think.

Comment: @KFGauss Yes it is true that the validity of the RPA is also determined by the density of carriers. If there is a high density of carriers than the approximation becomes better. However, I think the authors here try to say that even if the density is not that high, the fact that there are multiple valleys also justifies the RPA. I just don't completely understand why the higher diagrams are surpressed by 1/g.

Comment: I'll have to think about this. Off the top of my head I would say the statement is simply not true because you really need something like $KE/U>>1$ for RPA. This really requires a high density, as the number of species isn't relevant. But perhaps I'm not caught up with the current state of the field anymore.